# ConTeXt problems

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I am trying to typeset some recipes. I have already tried LaTeX and now I am trying the same/similar with ConTeXt. I am having huge problems with it. I have already been on this for two days and I cannot figure out what is the `context` compiler tell me to do/change/what is the problem. I have tried to figure things out myself. I have read parts of several documents related to ConTeXt: `cont-eni.pdf`, `ms-cb-en.pdf`, `mk.pdf`, `contextref.pdf`

Please see my MWE below. Could somebody point out the problems and suggest fixes/better ways to do this?

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\setupbodyfont[sansserif,9pt]
\language[cz]

\define[3]\Recipe{%
  \section[#1]{#2}%
    \startcolumns[n=2,rule=on]
      #3
    \stopcolumns}

\define[1]\Ingredients{%
  \subsubject{Ingredience}%
  \it
  \starttable[|r|l|]
    #1
  \stoptable}

\long\def\Steps#1{%
  \groupedcommand{\subsubject{Příprava}}{}{#1}}

%\showframe

\starttext
\startalignment[center]
  \title{Recepty}
  \currentdate
\stopalignment

\chapter{Bábovky}

\Recipe{babovka}{Bábovka}{%
  \Ingredients{%
    \NC 40~dkg \NC polohrubá mouka \NR
    \NC 15~dkg \NC cukr \NR
    \NC 10~dkg \NC tuk \NR
    \NC 1~ks \NC prášek do pečiva
  }
  \Steps{%
    A word word word word. \par Another word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word. \par Yet another word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word.\par
  }
}

Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between.

\Recipe{babovka2}{Bábovka}{%
  \Steps{%
    Word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word.}
}

\page
\completecontent

\stoptext
```

Compilation log:

```
(recepty.context.tex

ConTeXt  ver: 2012.05.30 11:26 MKIV  fmt: 2012.10.20  int: english/english

system          > cont-new.mkiv loaded
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv
system          > beware: some patches loaded from cont-new.mkiv
)
system          > no recepty.context.top
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language en is active
fonts           > preloading latin modern fonts (third stage)
fonts           > typescripts > unknown: library 'loc'
{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-math.map}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-rm.map}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/context/mkiv-base.map}
fonts           > virtual math > unable to resolve name mapsfromchar
fonts           > fallback modern ss 9pt is loaded
structure       > sectioning > title @ level 2 : 0.0 -> Recepty
backend         > xmp > using file '/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/lpdf-pdx.xml'
pages           > flushing realpage 1, userpage 1
structure       > sectioning > chapter @ level 2 : 0.1 -> Bábovky
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.1.1 -> Bábovka
structure       > sectioning > subsubject @ level 4 : 0.1.1.0 -> Ingredience
! Misplaced \noalign.

system          > tex > error on line 48 in file recepty.context.tex: Misplaced \noalign ...

38       \Steps{%
39         A word word word word. \par Another word word word word word word
40         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
41         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
42         word word word word word word word word. \par Yet another word
43         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
44         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
45         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
46         word word word word.\par
47       }
48 >>  }
49     
50     Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between.
51     
52     \Recipe{babovka2}{Bábovka}{%
53       \Steps{%
54         Word word word word word word word word word word word word word
55         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
56         word word word word word word word word word word word word word.}
57     }
58     


\tablenoalign ->\noalign 
                         \bgroup \let \noalign \relax \let \tablenoalign \re...
\starttablenoalign ->\tablenoalign 
                                   \bgroup 
\doinserttabletail ->\starttablenoalign 
                                        \global \settrue \preventtablebreak ...
\stoptable ...hucktableautorow \doinserttabletail 
                                                  \starttablenoalign \global...
<argument> ...R \NC 1~ks \NC prášek do pečiva }
                                                   \Steps {A word word word ...
\Recipe ... [#1]{#2}\startcolumns [n=2,rule=on] #3
                                                   \stopcolumns 
l.48 }

? 
! Misplaced \noalign.

system          > tex > error on line 48 in file recepty.context.tex: Misplaced \noalign ...

38       \Steps{%
39         A word word word word. \par Another word word word word word word
40         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
41         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
42         word word word word word word word word. \par Yet another word
43         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
44         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
45         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
46         word word word word.\par
47       }
48 >>  }
49     
50     Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between.
51     
52     \Recipe{babovka2}{Bábovka}{%
53       \Steps{%
54         Word word word word word word word word word word word word word
55         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
56         word word word word word word word word word word word word word.}
57     }
58     


\tablenoalign ->\noalign 
                         \bgroup \let \noalign \relax \let \tablenoalign \re...
\starttablenoalign ->\tablenoalign 
                                   \bgroup 
\doinserttabletail ...abletail \starttablenoalign 
                                                  \global \setfalse \prevent...
\stoptable ...hucktableautorow \doinserttabletail 
                                                  \starttablenoalign \global...
<argument> ...R \NC 1~ks \NC prášek do pečiva }
                                                   \Steps {A word word word ...
\Recipe ... [#1]{#2}\startcolumns [n=2,rule=on] #3
                                                   \stopcolumns 
l.48 }

? 
! Misplaced \noalign.

system          > tex > error on line 48 in file recepty.context.tex: Misplaced \noalign ...

38       \Steps{%
39         A word word word word. \par Another word word word word word word
40         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
41         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
42         word word word word word word word word. \par Yet another word
43         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
44         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
45         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
46         word word word word.\par
47       }
48 >>  }
49     
50     Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between.
51     
52     \Recipe{babovka2}{Bábovka}{%
53       \Steps{%
54         Word word word word word word word word word word word word word
55         word word word word word word word word word word word word word
56         word word word word word word word word word word word word word.}
57     }
58     


\tablenoalign ->\noalign 
                         \bgroup \let \noalign \relax \let \tablenoalign \re...
\starttablenoalign ->\tablenoalign 
                                   \bgroup 
\stoptable ...oinserttabletail \starttablenoalign 
                                                  \globalletempty \dotablehe...
<argument> ...R \NC 1~ks \NC prášek do pečiva }
                                                   \Steps {A word word word ...
\Recipe ... [#1]{#2}\startcolumns [n=2,rule=on] #3
                                                   \stopcolumns 
l.48 }

? 
structure       > sectioning > subsubject @ level 4 : 0.1.1.0 -> Příprava
columns         > balanced in 7 step(s)
structure       > sectioning > section @ level 3 : 0.1.2 -> Bábovka
structure       > sectioning > subsubject @ level 4 : 0.1.2.0 -> Příprava
columns         > balanced in 1 step(s)
pages           > flushing realpage 2, userpage 2
structure       > sectioning > title @ level 2 : 0.1 -> \headtext {content}
pages           > flushing realpage 3, userpage 3
 )</usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans9-oblique.otf></usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-regular.otf></usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans9-regular.otf>

system          > files > start used files

used files      >    1: filename=recepty.context.tex | foundname=recepty.context.tex | usedmethod=direct
used files      >    2: filename=cont-new.mkiv | filetype=tex | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/cont-new.mkiv | usedmethod=database
used files      >    3: filename=lang-us.lua | filetype=lua | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/patterns/lang-us.lua | usedmethod=database
used files      >    4: filename=lm.lfg | filetype=tex | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/fonts/lm.lfg | usedmethod=database
used files      >    5: filename=lm-math.lfg | filetype=tex | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/fonts/lm-math.lfg | usedmethod=database
used files      >    6: filename=lm-math.map | filetype=map | format=map | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-math.map | usedmethod=database
used files      >    7: filename=lm-rm.map | filetype=map | format=map | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/dvips/lm/lm-rm.map | usedmethod=database
used files      >    8: filename=mkiv-base.map | filetype=map | format=map | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/context/mkiv-base.map | usedmethod=database
used files      >    9: filename=lmsans9-regular | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans9-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   10: filename=lmroman5-regular.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman5-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   11: filename=rm-lmr5.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/rm-lmr5.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   12: filename=lmmi5.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmmi5.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   13: filename=lmsy5.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmsy5.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   14: filename=lmex10.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmex10.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   15: filename=msam5.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam5.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   16: filename=msbm5.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm5.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   17: filename=stmary10.afm | filetype=afm | format=afm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/stmaryrd/stmary10.afm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   18: filename=stmary10.pfb | filetype=pfb | format=pfb | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/stmaryrd/stmary10.pfb | usedmethod=database
used files      >   19: filename=lmroman5-bold | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman5-bold.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   20: filename=lmmib5.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmmib5.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   21: filename=lmsans8-regular.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans8-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   22: filename=lmmono8-regular.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono8-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   23: filename=eufm5.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/euler/eufm5.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   24: filename=lmroman7-regular.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman7-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   25: filename=rm-lmr7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/rm-lmr7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   26: filename=lmmi7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmmi7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   27: filename=lmsy7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmsy7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   28: filename=msam7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   29: filename=msbm7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   30: filename=lmroman7-bold.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman7-bold.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   31: filename=lmmib7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmmib7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   32: filename=eufm7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/euler/eufm7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   33: filename=eufb7.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/euler/eufb7.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   34: filename=lmroman9-regular.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman9-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   35: filename=rm-lmr9.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/rm-lmr9.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   36: filename=lmmi9.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmmi9.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   37: filename=lmsy9.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmsy9.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   38: filename=msam10.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msam10.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   39: filename=msbm10.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   40: filename=lmroman9-bold.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman9-bold.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   41: filename=lmmib10.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/tfm/public/lm/lmmib10.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   42: filename=lmsans9-regular.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans9-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   43: filename=lmmono9-regular.otf | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono9-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   44: filename=eufm10.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/euler/eufm10.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   45: filename=eufb10.tfm | filetype=tfm | format=tfm | foundname=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/euler/eufb10.tfm | usedmethod=database
used files      >   46: filename=lang-cs.lua | filetype=lua | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/patterns/lang-cs.lua | usedmethod=database
used files      >   47: filename=lmsans10-regular | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-regular.otf | usedmethod=database
used files      >   48: filename=lpdf-pdx.xml | filetype=tex | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/tex/context/base/lpdf-pdx.xml | usedmethod=database
used files      >   49: filename=lmsans9-oblique | filetype=otf | format=otf | foundname=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans9-oblique.otf | usedmethod=database

system          > files > stop used files


system          > structure > start used structure

used structure  > text: recepty.context

system          > structure > stop used structure


mkiv lua stats  > used config file          - selfautodir:/share/texmf/web2c/texmfcnf.lua
mkiv lua stats  > used cache path           - readable: '/var/lib/texmf/luatex-cache/context/f919750633122078d706dd10f1cfd39b' (order 1)
mkiv lua stats  > used cache path           - readable: '/home/wilx/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/f919750633122078d706dd10f1cfd39b' (order 2)
mkiv lua stats  > used cache path           - writable: '/home/wilx/.texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/f919750633122078d706dd10f1cfd39b'
mkiv lua stats  > resource resolver         - loadtime 0.059 seconds, 3 scans with scantime 0.002 seconds, 20 shared scans, 49 found files, scanned paths: /etc/texmf /home/wilx/.texmf-var /home/wilx/texmf
mkiv lua stats  > stored bytecode data      - 303 modules, 65 tables, 368 chunks
mkiv lua stats  > cleaned up reserved nodes - 39 nodes, 9 lists of 446
mkiv lua stats  > node memory usage         - 3 glue, 2 penalty, 16 attribute, 50 glue_spec, 4 attribute_list
mkiv lua stats  > node list callback tasks  - 6 unique task lists, 5 instances (re)created, 506 calls
mkiv lua stats  > used backend              - pdf (backend for directly generating pdf output)
mkiv lua stats  > loaded patterns           - cs::16 en::2
mkiv lua stats  > jobdata time              - 0.000 seconds saving, 0.000 seconds loading
mkiv lua stats  > callbacks                 - 802 direct, 590 indirect, 1392 total
mkiv lua stats  > lxml preparation time     - 0.000 seconds, 0 nodes, 11 lpath calls, 0 cached calls
mkiv lua stats  > result saved in file      - recepty.context.pdf
mkiv lua stats  > loaded fonts              - 37 files: stmary10.afm eufb10.tfm eufb7.tfm eufm10.tfm eufm5.tfm eufm7.tfm msam10.tfm msam5.tfm msam7.tfm msbm10.tfm msbm5.tfm msbm7.tfm lmmono8-regular.otf lmmono9-regular.otf lmroman5-bold.otf lmroman5-regular.otf lmroman7-bold.otf lmroman7-regular.otf lmroman9-bold.otf lmroman9-regular.otf lmsans10-regular.otf lmsans8-regular.otf lmsans9-oblique.otf lmsans9-regular.otf lmex10.tfm lmmi5.tfm lmmi7.tfm lmmi9.tfm lmmib10.tfm lmmib5.tfm lmmib7.tfm lmsy5.tfm lmsy7.tfm lmsy9.tfm rm-lmr5.tfm rm-lmr7.tfm rm-lmr9.tfm
mkiv lua stats  > fonts load time           - 0.220 seconds 
mkiv lua stats  > luatex banner             - this is luatex, version beta-0.70.2-2012091206 (tex live 2012/debian)
mkiv lua stats  > control sequences         - 33699 of 65536 + 100000
mkiv lua stats  > current memory usage      - 52 MB (ctx: 54 MB)
mkiv lua stats  > runtime                   - 2.058 seconds, 2 processed pages, 3 shipped pages, 1.458 pages/second
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The syntax for ConTeXt tables is:

```
\starttable[...]
  \NC ... \NC ... \NC \NR
  \NC ... \NC ... \NC \NR
\stoptable
```

You are missing the last `\NC`. If you add that, then the document compiles correctly.

However, I would use a different approach to markup the document.

1. Instead of

   ```
   \define[3]\Recipe{%
     \section[#1]{#2}%
       \startcolumns[n=2,rule=on]
         #3
       \stopcolumns}
   ```

   and

   ```
   \Recipe{reference}{title}
      {...}
   ```

   Use

   ```
   \definehead[recipe][section]
   \setuphead[recipe][beforesection={\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]}, aftersection={\stopcolumns}]
   ```

   and

   ```
   \startrecipe[reference={....}, title={....}]
     ....
   \stoprecipe
   ```
2. Instead of

   ```
   \define[1]\Ingredients{%
     \subsubject{Ingredience}%
     \it
     \starttable[|r|l|]
       #1
     \stoptable}

   \Ingredients{
     \NC ... \NC .. \NC \NR
     \NC ... \NC .. \NC \NR
   }
   ```

   use

   ```
   \definetabulate[ingredients][|r|l|]
   \setuptabulate[ingredients][before={\startsubsubject[title={Ingredience}]}, after={\stopsubsubject}]

   \startingredients
     \NC ... \NC .. \NC \NR
     \NC ... \NC .. \NC \NR
   \stopingredients
   ```
3. Instead of

   ```
   \long\def\Steps#1{%
     \groupedcommand{\subsubject{Příprava}}{}{#1}}
   ```

   and

   ```
     \Steps{...}
   ```

   use

   ```
     \definestartstop[steps][before={\startsubsubject[title={Příprava}]}, after={\stopsubsubject}]
   ```

   and

   ```
     \startsteps
       ....
     \stopsteps
   ```
4. Instead of

   ```
   \completecontent
   ```

   use

   ```
   \definecombinedlist[recipes][chapter,recipe]
   \setupheadtext[recipes={List of Recipes}]
   ```

   and

   ```
   \completerecipes%[criterium=all]
   ```

Thus, your document will look as follows:

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
\setupbodyfont[sansserif,9pt]
\language[cz]

\definehead[recipe][section]
\setuphead[recipe][beforesection={\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]}, aftersection={\stopcolumns}]

\definecombinedlist[recipes][chapter,recipe]
\setupheadtext[recipes={List of Recipes}]

\definetabulate[ingredients][|r|l|]
\setuptabulate[ingredients][before={\startsubsubject[title={Ingredience}]}, after={\stopsubsubject}]

\definestartstop[steps][before={\startsubsubject[title={Příprava}]}, after={\stopsubsubject}]

%\showframe

\starttext
\startalignment[center]
  \title{Recepty}
  \currentdate
\stopalignment

\chapter{Bábovky}

\startrecipe[title={Bábovka}, reference={babovka}]
  \startingredients
    \NC 40~dkg \NC polohrubá mouka \NC\NR
    \NC 15~dkg \NC cukr \NC \NR
    \NC 10~dkg \NC tuk \NC \NR
    \NC 1~ks \NC prášek do pečiva \NC \NR
  \stopingredients
  \startsteps
    A word word word word. \par Another word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word. \par Yet another word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word.\par
  \stopsteps
\stoprecipe

Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between. Between.

\startrecipe[title={Bábovka}, reference={babovka2}]
  \startsteps
    Word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word.
  \stopsteps
\stoprecipe

\page
\completerecipes[criterium=all]

\stoptext
```

This is more consistent with ConTeXt style of creating macros.

Comment: Wow! I totally did not expect the problem to be there. I thought it was in my `\def`s or `\define`s.

Comment: Actually, there is more elegant way of doing what you want. I'll update my answer to show that.

Comment: @wilx: See edited answer

Comment: I did not realize this earlier but in your rewrite, you have effectively switched the order of `\section[#1]{#2}` and `\startcolumns[n=2,rule=on]`. The section is inside the two columns. Can I keep the good style but restore the previous behaviour of the section being outside the two columns range?

Comment: @wilx: Change `beforesection=...` to `after=...`.